# Sumar columnas en R

Tags: r, excel, ciencia-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un estudio de [esta base de datos](https://www.kaggle.com/drgilermo/nba-players-stats-20142015) en R y quería sumar los datos de la columna FGM para cada equipo (columna Team). No encuentro manera de que me funcione. He probado esto, pero me da un error:

```
aggregate(PlayerStats$FGM ~ PlayerStats$Team, df[df$PlayerStats$PlayerStats$Team %in% c(ATL),], sum)
```

He puesto ATL porque no se como indicar todos los equipos.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginando que has importado los datos que mencionas en un `data.frame` llamado `df`, con `aggregate()` sería algo así:

```
aggregate(formula = FGM ~ Team, 
          data = df, 
          FUN = sum)
```

Es decir, agrupamos y aplicamos `sum` sobre `FGM` por cada `Team`. No es necesario, al especificar las variables en la formula: `FGM ~ Team` que indiques el `data.frame` ya que la función entiende estas variables en el contexto del `DATA`